# Create Dynamic TestFixture at runtime

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I am working on a project in which I have multiple .ini file(decide at runtime) in application directory and Want to create TestFixure for each ini file at runtime.

```
[TestFixture("card-1.ini")]     //HerdCode
[TestFixture("card-2.ini")]     //HerdCode
class ClassTest
{
    //test 
}
```

Here I have to do something which create  Parameterized TestFixture at run time.

Comment: Have a look at TestCase and TestCaseSource. Alternatively please be more specific regarding what you are asking

Comment: Actually I have to create a TestFixture for each ini files.